# How to get the IBM DB2 provider to work with Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: visual-studio, db2, entity-framework-4, provider

Can someone please tell me how to get the DB2 provider to show up in the "Change Data Source" dialog window?

Steps:

1. Right-click on the edmx design surface.
2. Select "Update Model from Database"
3. On the Update Wizard, click "New Connection"
4. Next to the "Data source" textbox, click "Change..."

In the Change Data Source window, I am only seeing the following data sources in the list:

```
Microsoft SQL Server
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5
Microsoft SQL Server Database File
<other>
```

When I select "other", I only see two entries in the Data Provider dropdown:

```
.Net Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5
.Net Framework Data Provider for SQL Server
```

How do I get the DB2 provider(s) to show up here so that I can use them to model my DB2 tables?

I am able to successfully connect to DB2 using the VS2010 Server Explorer. The Connection string for that is:

```
"Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Data Source=DB2THLOC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Location=****" (stars for security)
```

The Provider is listed as:

```
.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB
Type: DB2
Version: 08.01.0005
```

Many Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is enabled by the Visual Studio Add-In package from IBM.  Currently, there is no such package for vs2010.

Comment: Yes, I have since figured that out. I thought I saw that some people were using db2 with EF4, but apparently not yet. According the developer forum over at IBM, they are working hard to get a new release out that supports 2010 and EF4.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14462156

Comment: Actually, I am using DB2 with EF4 successfully right now, utilizing the method I mention in a comment/answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979473/do-net-framework-4-0-has-features-connecting-to-db2/2009262#2009262

Answer (score 0):

There already is proper providers. Drivers v9.7 FP4 or later work with VS 2010 EF 4.