# There is a IBM DB2 provider that works with Entity Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, db2, provider

There is already a DB2 provider to Entity Framework 4.0? I'm looking for one that shows up in the "Change Data Source" dialog window this way (in VS2010):

Steps:

Right-click on the edmx design surface.
Select "Update Model from Database"
On the Update Wizard, click "New Connection"
Next to the "Data source" textbox, click "Change..."
In the Change Data Source window, I am only seeing the following data sources in the list:

- Microsoft SQL Server
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Microsoft SQL
- Server Database File
- <'other'>

When I select "other", I only see two entries in the Data Provider dropdown:

- .Net Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5
- .Net Framework Data Provider for SQL Server

How do I get the DB2 provider(s) to show up here so that I can use them to model my DB2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of question [How to get the IBM DB2 provider to work with Entity Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722906/how-to-get-the-ibm-db2-provider-to-work-with-entity-framework-4-0) but 2 years have passed.

You need the DB2 Plug-In for Visual Studio 2010.  This is the only information I've found describing the plug-in: http://www.db2teamblog.com/2010/09/open-beta-for-visual-studio-2010.html

Comment: Thank you Gilbert. I had seen this question before, but as two years have passed, I had hoped that there was already an update available. . It was a great help, thanks.