# Is there a .net 4.0 provider for IBM DB2?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, db2

I can do any .Net development using v2 of the CLR (.net 2, 3, 3.5) but when I try to use .Net 4.0 then I get an error saying that the version of IBM.Data.DB2 is too old / out of date (it's compiled for CLR v2).

Where would I find a .Net 4 version of IBM.Data.DB2?

Answer (score 3):

IBM's policy towards providing updates is spelled out well in [this forum thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=317414&tstart=0).

Answer (score 2):

To connect to DB2 via .Net 4.0, you will need to download and install the Fix Pack 4 for version 9.7 of the IBM Data Connect software. Version 9.7 supports both x86 and x64 OS's and the fix pack 4 supports .Net 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a gander at the following question.  In my answer, I describe how I'm able to use DB2 drivers with vs2010 and clr 4:

[Does .Net Framework 4.0 have features for  connecting to DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979473/do-net-framework-4-0-has-features-connecting-to-db2/2009262#2009262)