# Visual Studio 2010 Entity Framework Addin for DB2 tables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, db2

Has anyone managed to get this to work?

Closest I have found is a comment on a deleted answer in this question: [Does .Net Framework 4.0 have features for  connecting to DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979473/do-net-framework-4-0-has-features-connecting-to-db2)

There it states:

> I never got the visual studio add-ins
>   working, which include the ability to
>   add tables from the dialog in EF.
>   Instead, I have to manually add to and
>   edit the storage schema (SSDL)
>   directly within the edmx XML.
>   (Right-click the .edmx file in
>   solution explorer, select "open
>   with...", and choose the XML editor.)

Very interested to here if anyone has got this to work without manually editing the xml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we have got it to work :)

But it does not handle composite keys automatically, you need to manually edit the edmx files.