# Can't use IBM DB2 Entity provider with F# TypeProviders

Tags: entity-framework, f#, db2, type-providers

I'm trying to test out the new F# Type Providers, but I can't get it to work nicely with our DB2 database.  This is my builder:

```
SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionString="Server=<host>:<port>;Database=<db>;UID=<uid>;PWD=<pwd>", Provider="IBM.Data.DB2">
```

All the appropriate libraries seem to be installed and configured, but I consistently get the error

```
Error reading schema. error 7001: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
```

I have no idea what to do here.  I'm referencing IBM.Data.DB2, IBM.Data.DB2.Entity, and IBM.Data.Informix in my project.  I tried the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979473/does-net-framework-4-0-have-features-for-connecting-to-db2/2009262#2009262) to fix up my machine.config and I applied it to app.config as well.  Nothing seems to work.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Does your database work with EF, without using type providers?